# dist-upgrade runs and completes but current kernel stays the same

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I think that my system is staying at an older kernel version. It seems to update when I run dist-upgrade but the current kernel version doesn't change.  Is it possible the system is set to install new kernel updates but only load an older version at start up?

```
$ uname -a
Linux HTPC 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:32:50 UTC 2012 i686 athlon    i386 GNU/Linux

$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic         3.2.0-32.51                                   Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic-pae     3.2.0-32.51                                Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-32-virtual         3.2.0-32.51                                  Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 Virtual Guests

dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
linux-headers-3.2.0-36
linux-headers-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-37
linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-38
linux-headers-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-39
linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-40
linux-headers-3.2.0-40-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-41
linux-headers-3.2.0-41-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-43
linux-headers-3.2.0-43-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-44
linux-headers-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-45
linux-headers-3.2.0-45-generic-pae
linux-headers-3.2.0-48
linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae
```

Update 7/1/13 11:43

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

Comment: maybe try `sudo update-grub`? also, i think the availability of `os-prober` may affect grub kernel discovery so make sure that's installed too

Answer (score 0):

Try installing packages linux-generic, linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic. These metapackages depend on latest kernel and headers. The most recently issued kernel should start by default, and you can check GRUB menu additional options for another actually installed kernels.

Comment: Can anyone confirm Danatelas' suggestion?  While I am happy to learn, I'd prefer a bit more detail before installing any packages. On that note this is a minimal install of 12.04 server.

Comment: @jaguare22, you can try `apt-get --simulate` to see what actually does the installation of these packages. And I also doubt you really need so many versions of headers installed.

Comment: Thanks Danatela.  I am a little confused though, this system actually works fine.  I jus thought I'd clean out some of the old kernels when I discovered the apparent problem.  I do appreciate your comments and I'll be working to better understand dependencies.

Comment: Hi Danatela, thanks again for your answer.  It was right on the money.  Since this system was built from a minimal install for a specific function I needed to be sure I wasn't adding anything that could hose it up.  Anyway, thanks again for taking the time to help me out.  If you have any suggestions for reading about the relationship of the kernel and the metapackages I'd be happy to hear about them.  - J